# Discord.py / display messages of a specific user?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I need to display in the chat using the bot the last 10-20 messages of a certain user that he wrote on the entire server (in any channel). How can I do that?

used

```
messages = []
    async for message in ctx.channel.history(limit=100):
        if message.author.id == member:
            messages += [message]
```

understood nothing
need help, preferably with an example

Answer (score -2):

Hi for an entire server can be quite heavy but this will give you last 100 messages from a channel, you can set `limit=None` to get all mesages in a channel

```py
 messages = [message async for message in channel.history(limit=100) if message.author.id == member]
```

For the server, you could iterate through all the channels in the server, and in each iteration, iterate through all the messages again. This will take an awful long time, but i dont really see another way to do it.